# Email client that understands both HTML and maildir

Tags: email, software-rec, mail-user-agent, maildir

I'm using Mutt as my main email client, but I'm looking for another one for my work email (because of HTML email). I need one that can handle my existing Maildir email, to be able to switch between Mutt and the new one without having to import/export my old emails.

Does anyone know such email client?.

Also I don't want to stop using Fetchmail, Procmail and Exim4. It would be nice to find something similar to Mutt, but with better HTML answering abilities.

Answer (score 2):

## Local email for multiple email cleints [IMAP]

Have you considered using "maildir ready" IMAP server?
It will allow you to access your maildir by many/most email clients.
You may consider "maildir ready" [Dovecot IMAP server](http://www.dovecot.org/) as "an option zero".

AFAIK two email clients (Evolution and Emacs/Gnus) can use Dovecot in server-less mode to access your personal maildir.

Comment: Thanks Andrzej, I've installed dovecot and tried it with Claws-Mail, but the former doesn't allow HTML editing. Do you know something lightweight for HTML emails?.

Comment: Googling for "lightweight linux IMAP client" gets me a lot of hits for Geary. I have never tried it, though.

Comment: It seems that Geary fits my needs.